# Android: Implementing WhatsApp File Picker

Tags: android, material-design

I want to implement something like WhatsApp file picker in Android, but I do not really know how to do it.
WhatsApp Android version has a nice file picker ripple transition and I want to implement it in my app.
Is there any ready component to do something like this or maybe I should extend a dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have also been searching for a library like that for ages and today, I found it here 
[Universal Media Picker](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6862)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkbGK.png)

Try it out and let me know if you liked it :)